# What do you say when you have done something and must sign a document indicating that it has been done

Tags: phrase-requests

The question is in the title but an example sentence would be:

*Every party must read the overarching obligations and sign a document ............*

A wordy way to say it is:
*Every party must read the overarching obligations and sign a document indicating they have done so.*

I feel like there must be a more formal way of stating it.

Would "to that nature" work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every party must read the overarching obligations and sign a document *to indicate assent*.

Works well to convey the sense of formality you mentioned.

***[Assent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assent)***

> 1) The expression of approval or agreement.
>
> 1.1) Official agreement or sanction.

(Oxford)

You could also use *endorse*:

Every party must read the overarching obligations and sign a document to *endorse them*.

***[Endorse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/endorse)***

> 1) Declare one's public approval or support of.
>
> ‘the report was endorsed by the college’

(Oxford)

*To that nature* doesn't work as you haven't articulated a particular nature, just the act of having read the document.

Answer (score 1):

How about something along the lines of signing to acknowledge:

> All parties must sign this document acknowledging they have read the overarching obligations.